# Create a FAT32 disk image on Windows using command line?

Tags: windows, disk-image

Is there any command-line tool on Windows that can create a FAT32 disk image (similar to Linux using `dd` and `mkfs.vfat`, then mount the disk image for modifying?

Comment: Do you mean creating a file that is structured as though it were a volume, like a virtual disk, as contrasted with actually formatting a partition or removable media?

Comment: Relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/277912/does-windows-7-have-built-in-support-for-creating-mounting-disk-images?rq=1

Comment: If you are OK with a VHD image (which is a Microsoft specific format) the answer Jeff Zeitlin linked to answers your question. If you need a RAW image you can mount the VHD and then do a regular DD copy of the mounted disk to a RAW file. There are Windows versions of DD available, Cygwin exists and recent versions of Windows 10 have the Linux subsystem  available which also includes DD.

Comment: It might be noteworthy that a fixed-size VHD image is virtually RAW, except for a small header at the end.